# Issues with installing Mono 2.6.7 in Mac 10.4.7

Tags: macos, mono, libsystem

I'm installing Mono 2.6.7 on a Mac 10.4.7, and running across few issues. I've solved some of them by updating few libraries via MacPort, but this one is the latest.

When I start Mono, it crashes. Any help is appreciated.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _strerror$UNIX2003
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.6.7/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _strerror$UNIX2003
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.6.7/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved by installing macports, and then doing a

```
sudo port install mono
```

Which essentially downloads mono and related dependencies, and compile mono against the local libraries.

Answer (score 1):

OS X's system libraries often contain multiple versions of standard C functions. Starting 10.5, OS X supports the [Single Unix Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Mac_OS_X_and_Mac_OS_X_Server). The `stderror` function as in BSD behaves slightly differently in SUS. So, the library has two versions, `_stderror` and `_stderror$UNIX2003`. Which to use is determined at the compile time, as described [here](http://tuvix.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/compat.5.html), using C preprocessor macros.

I think the Mono binary you're using was compiled in a newer environment. You need to recompile it. If you recompile it on 10.4 machine, it should automatically use the non-UNIX2003 version and it should run fine.

By the way, seriously, update 10.4.7 to 10.4.11.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the note. As I'm pretty sure on this, just want to check if I can do the recompilation via macports or something - or whether I've to get the Mono svn from repository and do it manually?

Comment: `libSystem` is the very basic shared library and you don't want to mess with it. Re-compiling mono would be safer. What error did you resolve via macports? Did you replace libraries in `/usr/lib/`?